# reference to findViewById is ambiguous

Tags: android

I tell you a few days ago that I could not debug my application, then I reinstalled the android studio and updated the latest version, now that I want to continue with my project in each of the activities where I use `"findViewById (R.id.nombre )"` the following error appears:

```
Error: (23, 31) error: reference to findViewById is ambiguous
both method findViewById (int) in Activity and method <T> findViewById (int) in AppCompatActivity match
where T is a type-variable:
T extends View declared in method <T> findViewById (int)
```

I have already searched here, but my problem is still I hope you can help me, I attach some captures

[exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7Krv.png)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwTCo.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're using `findViewById (R.id.nombre )`. Where nombre is defined in two activities(Activity and AppCompatActivity) with same name. You should assign different name for nombre in each activity.

Comment: This is not correct. `R.id` fields are not defined in `Activity` classes, and even if they were, those would be in completely separate scopes. Furthermore, the conflict is coming from the method, not the argument.